# Serialise shell commands

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm looking for a way to "stack" commands from the terminal prompt so that only one at the time is executed:

- First enter a command, press enter, execution starts, back to shell (like `&`)
- I can enter a second command. I press enter, the first command is not completed yet so it is stacked (unlike `&`). But again, the prompt is back.

Kind of a mix between:

- `&` to launch in the background, but the second command would run at the same time as the first one, and I don't want that;
- `&&` or `;` to launch one command after the other, but you have to write them all in once. I want to regain the prompt after the command is executed or stacked.

The closest I've found would be:

```
$ cmd1 &
$ wait; cmd2 &
```

But I'm looking for something a bit more potent, allowing me to view pending, failed and completed commands. Maybe something like:

```
$ stackit cmd1
cmd1 started
$ stack it cmd2
cmd2 queued
$ stack it cmd3
cmd3 queued
$ stack it --
[1] running
[2] queued
[3] queued
```

Maybe to even allow for some parallelism, like 2 commands at the time.

This seems fairly generic so I don't feel like re-inventing the wheel.

Use cases:

- Copying files to and from an old NAS that suffers when several operations run at the same time
- wget on a large number of files where a limited number of connections would be preferred

Comment: This might be a bit of an overkill, but maybe [slurm](http://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.html) will help you

Comment: It seems indeed overkill but it's good to know it exists.

Comment: I don't think it exists, but *scripted* everything can be done, e.g. create a command `addcommand <command>`  to add a command to the (a) queue. Overkill?

Comment: Bunch of options at: http://superuser.com/q/220364/334516

Comment: Very interesting @muru. Your comment could be an answer to my question. Not all the suggested seem to actually work, but it's actually a good pointer. Thanks.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged here. Perhaps you could post some of the methods that did work for you as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for the [task spooler](http://vicerveza.homeunix.net/~viric/soft/ts/) command. In the Debian/Ubuntu's repositories, the pacakage to install is `task-spooler` and the binary to call is `tsp`.

In your case (`&&` style) you could use

```
tsp -d cmd1
tsp -d cmd2
tsp -d cmd3
```

then use

```
tsp -l
```

to inspect the status of the queue.

There are ways (`-S`) to increase the number of max simultanious jobs, too.

Answer (score 0):

Although `bash` in and of itself doesn't have the "queue" or "stack" type of job control, but they do have  job control (which has existed for years, way back to `korn` shell of Unix System V ) whereby you can put the processes in background, and control them with `kill` command

```
DIR:/coreutils
skolodya@ubuntu:$ gedit &> /dev/null &
[1] 26742

DIR:/coreutils
skolodya@ubuntu:$ gnome-terminal &> /dev/null &                                
[2] 26767

DIR:/coreutils
skolodya@ubuntu:$ jobs                                                         
[2] + Running              gnome-terminal >/dev/null 2>&1 
[1] - Running              gedit >/dev/null 2>&1 

DIR:/coreutils
skolodya@ubuntu:$ kill -SIGSTOP %1                                             

DIR:/coreutils
skolodya@ubuntu:$ jobs
[1] + Stopped (signal)     gedit >/dev/null 2>&1 
[2] - Running              gnome-terminal >/dev/null 2>&1 

DIR:/coreutils
skolodya@ubuntu:$ kill -SIGCONT %1                                             

DIR:/coreutils
skolodya@ubuntu:$ jobs                                                         
[1] + Stopped (signal)     gedit >/dev/null 2>&1 
[2] - Running              gnome-terminal >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The output of those commands in the above example goes to `/dev/null`, but of course if that's a command line app, you want to redirect output somewhere you can view it later. For instance, a `named pipe`.

```
DIR:/coreutils
skolodya@ubuntu:$ mkfifo test.fifo                                             

DIR:/coreutils
skolodya@ubuntu:$ apt-cache search 1> test.fifo &
[1] 27775

DIR:/coreutils
skolodya@ubuntu:$ cat test.fifo | head -n 3                                    
screen - terminal multiplexer with VT100/ANSI terminal emulation
screen-dbg - Debugging symbols for GNU Screen
asic0x-dkms - iBurst USB modem driver in DKMS format
```

Here I am redirecting `stdout` (file descriptor 1 ) to a pipe I created, and review it later. This can be done with multiple commands, by creating multiple named pipes.

**Side note**: One could script something with these options, at least IMHO, it's easier to just use these job control methods by themselves.

Comment: In fact . . . I might try to script something just for fun . . .but that's no promise

Comment: I don't think this answers the requirement for "the first command is not completed yet so it is stacked". The key point lies in the title: "Serialise shell commands".